# Теоретическая оценка вычислительной сложности алгоритма в среднем, лучшем и худшем случаях, оцените асимптотическую сложность

Tags: python, алгоритм, сложность

подскажите, пожалуйста, как оценить сложность этого алгоритма. Алгоритм заменяет нули на предыдущее не нулевое значение.

```
a = [3,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,4,0]
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(i if i else b[-1])
print (b)
```

Я только третий день начала изучать питон, не очень понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш вопрос к пайтону особо отношения не имеет. Это относится к теме о сложности алгоритмов. В данном случае у вас сложность О(n) - линейная сложность. Естественно, как определять сложность алгоритмов в рамках одного ответа, объяснить невозможно. Поэтому рекомендую почитать литературу или погуглить тему "Оценка сложности алгоритмов".

Comment: Не совсем так. В зависимости от реализации list.append() сложность может меняться от линейной до квадратичной

Comment: Возможно, я не по пайтон, не в курсе как в пайтоне append реализовано, но подозреваю что реализовать должны были с линейной сложность по аналогии с остальными языками

Comment: @had0uken если у append линейная сложность, то в целом алгоритм будет иметь квадратичную сложность. Для python у append сложность примерно константная, "но не совсем" (при росте списка в какой-то момент возникнет необходимость перемещения его в больший блок памяти). В целом, если говорить про разные языки, то лучше не полагаться, что во всех языках сложность добавления элемента в конец константная.

Comment: Вот тут в исходниках есть пояснение, по какому принципу выполняется ресайз блока памяти списка (в том числе при append): https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/616fcad6e2e10b0d0252e7f3688e61c468c54e6e/Objects/listobject.c#L61 . Я так сходу сложность с учетом необходимости перемещения данных не оценю, но она явно не константная, скорее линейная с довольно маленьким множителем, либо логарифмическая в лучшем случае. Нужно смотреть, по по какому принципу растет размер выделяемого блока, вроде бы не совсем линейно (4 - 8 - 16 - 24 в линию не ложатся).